# MAMP, installing PECL event

Tags: php, macos, socket.io, pecl, libevent

I want in install `pecl event` using

```
pecl install event
```

I have followed this so far, http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-mamp-mac-os-x-107-lion, with limited success.

I get the following error

> configure: error: Please reinstall the event library, or provide the
>   installation prefix via --with-event-libevent-dir option
>
> ERROR:
>   `/private/tmp/pear/temp/event/configure --enable-event-debug=no
>   --enable-event-sockets=yes --with-event-libevent-dir=/usr --with-event-pthreads=no --with-event-extra --with-event-openssl --with-openssl-dir=no' failed

This looks like it requires `pecl libevent`

So I have now run

```
pecl install libevent-beta
```

This results in the following error

> configure: error: Cannot find libevent headers ERROR:
>
> `/private/tmp/pear/temp/libevent/configure --with-libevent' failed

I know it 'could' work because `pecl install uploadprogress` was successful.

How can I install `pecl event`?

It might be worth stating my final goal is getting Socket.IO to work (https://github.com/RickySu/phpsocket.io)

Answer (score 0):

pecl-event's configuration tries to find libevent headers in `/usr/local` `/usr` `/opt` `/opt/local`. I'm not an OS X user, but I guess it should install stuff into `/opt/local`.

> This looks like it requires pecl libevent

Nope! It doesn't require PECL's libevent! You have to install [libevent](http://libevent.org/) itself. Hmm, I guess:

```
port install libevent
```

or maybe

```
port install libevent-dev
```

You should figure it out. Anyhow, to build pecl-event you need libevent's binaries and headers.
Those should be provided by packages like "libevent", "libevent-dev" or similar.

Alternatively, you can install libevent from source. Be sure to check if it's going to install into some "popular" location like `/usr`, `/usr/local` etc. By means of `--with-event-libevent-dir` `configure` option one can provide path to libevent's installation directory.

Btw, I'm a maintainer of pecl-event. Feel free to [report issues](https://bitbucket.org/osmanov/pecl-event).